# the strange value of SRE in a D-SACK packet

Tags: tcp, wireshark, lvs

I'm troubleshooting a strange network issue in our production environment.

The dumped pcap file comes from the full NAT mode LVS , and the toploy of the ip address in the dump file is:

172.19.132.90（client）-> 172.52.0.3, 172.16.246.46 -> 172.16.211.57(server)

The dumped file's snapshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwiWY.jpg

I noticed the SRE value in the D-SACK is unbelievable BIG! Also the ack package isn't received by our client.(I also dump a file on 172.19.132.90 and cannot see the ACK)

My questions are
Why the SRE is so big?
Is that the reason the ACK failed to be received by the client?